# WinAppDriver Selenium Switching to DIfferent App C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, winappdriver

Trying to open an app from another app and switch control to the app that opened. WinAppDriver does open the app but it doesn’t recognize the newly opened window.

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
        public void TestInit()
        {
            _newProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");

            var options = new AppiumOptions();
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"Launcher.exe path");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("seleniumVersion", "3.4.0");
            _driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
            TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, interval);
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        }

[Test]
        public void RunGraphEditor()
        {
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("mProgramComboBox").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Text[@ClassName=\"TextBlock\"][@Name=\"GraphEditor\"]").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Text[@ClassName=\"TextBlock\"][@Name=\"Run\"]").Click();
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            
            
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window("WindowName");
           
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//MenuItem[@ClassName=\"MenuItem\"][@Name=\"Tools\"]")));
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//MenuItem[@ClassName=\"MenuItem\"][@Name=\"Tools\"]").Click();
            
        }
```